Import error when tried to import umap on my MacBook Pro M1
I tried to run a python script on my MacBook Pro M1 laptop. And I encountered the following error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 3
      1 import openai
      2 import pandas as pd
----> 3 from umap import umap_ as UMAP
      4 from hdbscan import HDBSCAN
      5 from bertopic.representation import OpenAI

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bertopic/lib/python3.9/site-packages/umap/__init__.py:2
      1 from warnings import warn, catch_warnings, simplefilter
----> 2 from .umap_ import UMAP
      4 try:
      5     with catch_warnings():

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bertopic/lib/python3.9/site-packages/umap/umap_.py:10
      7 from warnings import warn
      8 import time
---> 10 from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
     11 from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator
     12 from sklearn.utils import check_random_state, check_array

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bertopic/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/optimize/__init__.py:400
      1 """
      2 =====================================================
      3 Optimization and root finding (:mod:`scipy.optimize`)
   (...)
    397 :mod:`Additional information on the nonlinear solvers <scipy.optimize.nonlin>`
    398 """
--> 400 from .optimize import *
    401 from ._minimize import *
    402 from ._root import *

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bertopic/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py:36
     32 import numpy as np
     33 from .linesearch import (line_search_wolfe1, line_search_wolfe2,
     34                          line_search_wolfe2 as line_search,
     35                          LineSearchWarning)
---> 36 from ._numdiff import approx_derivative
     37 from scipy._lib._util import getfullargspec_no_self as _getfullargspec
     38 from scipy._lib._util import MapWrapper

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bertopic/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_numdiff.py:6
      3 import numpy as np
      4 from numpy.linalg import norm
----> 6 from scipy.sparse.linalg import LinearOperator
      7 from ..sparse import issparse, csc_matrix, csr_matrix, coo_matrix, find
      8 from ._group_columns import group_dense, group_sparse

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bertopic/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/__init__.py:111
      1 """
      2 Sparse linear algebra (:mod:`scipy.sparse.linalg`)
      3 ==================================================
   (...)
    108 
    109 """
--> 111 from .isolve import *
    112 from .dsolve import *
    113 from .interface import *

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bertopic/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/isolve/__init__.py:4
      1 "Iterative Solvers for Sparse Linear Systems"
      3 #from info import __doc__
----> 4 from .iterative import *
      5 from .minres import minres
      6 from .lgmres import lgmres

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bertopic/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/isolve/iterative.py:8
      5 import warnings
      6 import numpy as np
----> 8 from . import _iterative
     10 from scipy.sparse.linalg.interface import LinearOperator
     11 from .utils import make_system

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/lima/anaconda3/envs/bertopic/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/isolve/_iterative.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002): Library not loaded: @rpath/liblapack.3.dylib
  Referenced from: <F6B2F3DE-67F2-3432-A7FE-8F2AB8BC709B> /Users/lima/anaconda3/envs/bertopic/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/isolve/_iterative.cpython-39-darwin.so
  Reason: tried: '/Users/lima/anaconda3/envs/bertopic/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/isolve/../../../../../../liblapack.3.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/lima/anaconda3/envs/bertopic/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/isolve/../../../../../../liblapack.3.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/lima/anaconda3/envs/bertopic/bin/../lib/liblapack.3.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/lima/anaconda3/envs/bertopic/bin/../lib/liblapack.3.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/liblapack.3.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/liblapack.3.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)

I tried to save this problem by trying different approaches, such as recreating a Conda environment, change the import script from from umap import UMAP into import umap.umap_ as UMAP, however none of these solutions worked...
My laptop is a MacBook Pro with M1 chip. May I know how to get this problem fixed?
Thank you.

I doubt if the type of computer is relevant. Try listing your installed modules and ensure that umap-learn is there

Have a look at: sklearn can't find lapack in new conda environment, as the root issue is: Library not loaded: @rpath/liblapack.3.dylib

Thank you @MauriceMeyer, you comment helped me to get this problem fixed.
